# NSEPY is not working.Timeout error while connecting

Tags: python, stock, algorithmic-trading, nsepy

I am using nsepy for data analysis since more than one year.But its not working now days. i did all possible try to fix this ,uninstall and reinstall .tried with both python 2.7 and 3.7 but nothing is working it seems . all the time same timeout error while connecting to server. So it it NSE india has stopped data service via API?

Answer (score 0):

It was required me to upgrade request package . Now its working fine.